# How to uniquely identify an element in Selenium?

Tags: java, sockets, selenium

I want to be able to uniquely identify an element in Selenium so that, let's say person A clicks on element x, I can send a packet to person B letting them know that an element was clicked and that the element is x. The programs will be separate and so I can't just send the WebElement object over a socket. How can I uniquely identify an element in a way that it can be sent over a socket and be accurate every time?

I want to do this so that person A can execute actions on the browser that's actually hosted on person B's computer. Person A's view of the browser would be identical to person B's, but all actions executed on the browser would actually be done on person B's computer, and person A's browser would be more of a mirror (with the ability to click elements and type) of the real browser on person B's computer.

Comment: Why would you want to be dealing with Sockets in this case? If your webapp handles all this integration internally between itself and an external system and the environment is configurable for a runtime test scenario then you should just start your webapp with the integration in place and test it simulating a user interacting with a browser. You just need to map your elements with IDs and use that to uniquely identify a page element

Comment: Huh? It's not through a web app. The browser hosted on person B's computer will be used to browse specific websites and run certain selenium scripts. How else would I have person B and person A exchange data without using sockets?

Mapping the elements with an id sounds like a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, what you should do is assign `id` values to the elements you care about. The algorithm would have to be such that two elements cannot get the same `id` but that the assignment of `id` values can be predicted so that two elements in the same location in two identically structured DOM trees will get the same `id`. It *could* be something as banal as numbering all `button` elements from 1 in document order. The `id` is what you use to uniquely identify a `button`.

If you cannot know the elements you care about ahead of time, then you have to use another method. I've done something like this for one of my applications. What I do is create a path where each step of the path is the index of the DOM node among the children of its parent. This path can be used to uniquely identify an element. In your case, the root that serves as the first reference point could be the `body` element. A path would look something like this `/1/4/1/2` which (reading backwards) refers to child 2 of the child 1 of the child 4 of the child 1 of `body`. (The indexes are 0-based.) It would be possible to create an path in a format that would be compatible with XPath if you have some use for that. For instance, `/ul[2]/li[5]/ul[2]/li[3]`. (Reminder: XPath indexes are 1-based.) In my project, I don't need XPath compatibility (nor is it beneficial in any way *in my project*).

There is one major caveat: **The DOM tree on both sides have to have the same structure.**

For instance. If on one side, you have:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
<body>
```

Then you should have the same on the other side, because if someone clicks on the last `li` and you need to identify the element on the other side, you'll have a problem if the DOM tree is representing this:

```
<body>
  <p>foo</p>
<body>
```

How you ensure that your trees have the same structure is wholly dependent on your specific application.

The first method I described using `id` values is more tolerant of differences in structure. If you care only about `button` elements and, on both sides, you have `button` elements that appear in the order "Checkout", "Empty Cart", "Remove Item" and that they perform the same functions on both sides, then it does not matter what ancestors they have in their respective DOM tree. However, the order and number of `button` elements still matter.